# Is the category of groupoids a Lawvere thory?

Tags: category-theory, groupoids

By which I mean a category of models for a Lawvere theory.

I have not seen this anywhere, so I wonder if something goes wrong with this category.

Comment: If you have a new question, you should pose it by posting a new question, not by changing the meaning of an existing one, especially given that the existing question has been answered.

Comment: There's a big difference between "a Lawvere theory" and "a category of models for a Lawvere theory."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't mean [magmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)), the answer is "no".  Categories and groupoids are not models of a Lawvere theory because composition isn't a total operation.  However, they *are* [essentially algebraic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essentially+algebraic+theory) which is very similar to being a model of a Lawvere theory.  Basically, instead of finite-product preserving functors, you consider finite *limit* preserving functors.  This is needed because composition is only defined over a pullback.  Roughly, an essentially algebraic theory is like an algebraic theory except that you are allowed to have "partial" operations.

Comment: Sure.  An [internal groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category#internal_groupoid) is exactly that.